# Mixed array of numbers and strings

Tags: interface, typescript

How can I create an interface for an array that accepts both numbers and strings?

Since inside the function `[1,'1']`, `['1','1']`,`[1,1]` are equivalent (they are joined inside as `'1.1'`), I can't seem to satisfy the compiler. It gets me `TS2087: Could not select overload for 'call' expression.`

works for `fn([1,1]);` and `fn(['1','1']);` but not mixed values.

Comment: Nope, no algebraic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. I suggest to use `any[]`:

```
function fn(arr: any[]) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
fn([1, 1]);
fn(['1', '1']);
fn(['1', 1]);
```